# systemd: b requires a, stop a if b stops

Tags: systemd

This is `b.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=b.service
ConditionPathExists=/usr/sbin/b
Requires=a.service
BindsTo=a.service
After=a.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/b
```

This does almost all I want:

- If b.service starts, then a.service starts.
- If a.service starts, then b.service starts.
- If a.service stops, then b.service stops.

I would like to add the remaining dependency: **if b.service stops, then a.service stops**, *without modifying the service file of a.service, if possible*.

Comment: The dependency you want is "a requires b". Are you 100% sure about this?

Comment: Well, if a isn't there, then b has no purpose running. If b isn't there, a can't work correctly. So, yeah?

Comment: So you actually have a circular dependency? Are you really sure about this? It is NOT normal.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1025126/why-is-systemd-not-bringing-down-dependencies suggests using a .target unit to coordinate multiple services

Comment: It just came to me that I can actually install an override file for a.service where I `BindsTo=b.service`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now additionally created an override for a.service in */etc/systemd/system/a.service.d/override.conf* which defines:

```
[Unit]
BindsTo=b.service
```

Like this, a full dependency *a if and only if b* is fulfilled.